# Load async images in Swift for iOS app not working

Tags: ios, swift, image, asynchronous, load

I'm trying to load the image async in my tableview, to be able to read them 'offline'.

The images display correctly when i'm having a connexion. otherwise, it doesn't when I don't have any connexion so its not working. . .

here is the code i am using:

```
 import UIKit
 import FirebaseAuth
 import FirebaseDatabase
 import FirebaseStorage
 import SwiftKeychainWrapper
 import SwiftyJSON

 var posts = [Post]()
 var selectedIndexPath: Int = 10

 class FeedVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, 
 UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, 
 UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var feedTableView: UITableView!

private var readPosts: ObserveTask?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    feedTableView.dataSource = self
    feedTableView.delegate = self

    readPosts = Post.observeList(from: Post.parentReference.queryOrdered(byChild: "privacy").queryEqual(toValue: false))

    {
        observedPosts in

        posts = observedPosts.reversed()
        self.feedTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  {
    let cell = self.feedTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MessageCell")! as UITableViewCell


 let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! CustomImageView



    let titleLabel = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    let linkLabel = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel

    titleLabel.text = posts[indexPath.row].title
    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0

    linkLabel.text = posts[indexPath.row].link
    linkLabel.numberOfLines = 0



    Storage.getImage(with: posts[indexPath.row].imageUrl){
        postPic in
        imageView.image = postPic
    }

    return cell




}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard posts[indexPath.row].title != "COMING SOON" else {
        return
    }
           selectedIndexPath = indexPath.row
          self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "push", sender: self)
            self.feedTableView.reloadData()    }



 }

 let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()

 class CustomImageView: UIImageView{

 var imageUrlString: String?

 func loadImageUsingUrlString(urlString: String){

    imageUrlString = urlString

    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

    image = nil

    if let imageFromCache = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as AnyObject) as? UIImage{

        self.image = imageFromCache
        return

    }

    URLSession.shared
        .dataTask(with: url! as URL, completionHandler:
            {(data, respones, error) in

                if error != nil{
                    print(error)



                    return
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: {

                    let imageToCache = UIImage(data: data!)

                    if self.imageUrlString == urlString{

                    self.image = imageToCache

                    }

                    imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)

                    self.image = imageToCache
                }
                )

        }).resume()

}

 }
```

I'm having my async function from the class class CustomImageView.

I'm usually calling the image via:

```
Storage.getImage(with: posts[indexPath.row].imageUrl){
    postPic in
    imageView.image = postPic
}
```

I suppose the problem is coming from that part ? ( i am not sur)

Does anybody have any highlight of what is wrong within my process ?

Thanks a lot for your help !!

-- EDIT --

the image storage is being call via:

```
 import Foundation
 import FirebaseStorage
 import UIKit

 let STORAGE_BASE = FIRStorage.storage().reference()

 class Storage
 {
static let REF_POST_IMAGES = STORAGE_BASE.child("post-pics")
static let REF_USER_IMAGES = STORAGE_BASE.child("user-pics")

static let imageCache: NSCache<NSString, UIImage> = NSCache()

static func upload(image: UIImage, to reference: FIRStorageReference, completionHandler: @escaping (String?, Error?) -> ())
{
    // Uploads the image
    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.2)
    {
        let imageUid = NSUUID().uuidString
        let metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

        reference.child(imageUid).put(imageData, metadata: metadata)
        {
            (metadata, error) in

            if let error = error
            {
                completionHandler(nil, error)
            }

            if let downloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
            {
                // Caches the image for faster display
                imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: downloadURL as NSString)
                completionHandler(downloadURL, nil)
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        completionHandler(nil, StorageError.compressionFailed)
    }
}

// Storage.imageCache.object(forKey: post.imageUrl as NSString)
static func getImage(with url: String, completionHandler: @escaping (UIImage) -> ())
{
    if let image = imageCache.object(forKey: url as NSString)
    {
        completionHandler(image)
    }
    else
    {
        let ref = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: url)
        ref.data(withMaxSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024)
        {
            (data, error) in

            if let error = error
            {
                print("STORAGE: Unable to read image from storage \(error)")
            }
            else if let data = data
            {
                print("STORAGE: Image read from storage")
                if let image = UIImage(data: data)
                {
                    // Caches the image
                    Storage.imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: url as NSString)
                    completionHandler(image)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
 }

 enum StorageError: Error
 {
case compressionFailed
 }
```

Comment: Is the closure of `getImage` is getting called, but that `postPic` is `nil`? Is the `posts[indexPath.row].imageUrl` good? If yes to both of those, then the problem rests in `getImage` implementation, not your `UITableViewDataSource` implementation.

Comment: the posts[indexPath.row].imageUrl is good i believe as image display when i'm having an internet connexion . ..  i have update the code with my storage code if that help ?

Thanks a lot for your time :)

Comment: If you are familiar with using SDWebImage, you can consider substituting that with your custom Image Cache code.

Comment: You are using `NSCache`, which will cache the images in memory, only. Thus, if the app terminates, the cache is gone. If you want to cache it persistently, you have to write it to your caches directory (`NSCachesDirectory`).

Comment: @JenJose - IIRC, SDWebImage purges its persistent cache when the app terminates and/or enters background.

Comment: @Rob when i replace NSCAche by     static let imageCache: NSCachesDirectory<NSString, UIImage> = NSCachesDirectory()
 i'm getting a 'Use of undeclared type 'NSCachesDirectory' what can be done ?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I wasn't clear. `NSCachesDirectory` is used by [`url(for:...)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/filemanager/1407693-url) to get the URL for the cache directory. You have to manually read and write the image data to a file in that directory. You generally do it in addition to (and as a fall back for) `NSCache`.

Comment: hmm, it sounds really too complex too me :( do you have any example by any chance ?

Comment: any idea by any chances :( ?